# How to do something when someones mentions you ? (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make my bot add a reaction when someones pings me, but when I get the list of the mentions in the message, all the elements types are . I'm trying to use a if inside the event on_message, here is my code :

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if discord.User.id(343113425158668289) in message.mentions:
        await message.add_reaction('')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

but this gives me an error : TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable
I want to compare my id with the ones in the list, and add the reaction if the bot detects my ping.
Does anyone have a solution ? (Sorry if my English is bad, it's not my native language)
I'm using python 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #For every @member in message
    for member in message.mentions:
    #look if the member ID is equal to your ID (343113425158668289)
        if 343113425158668289 == member.id:
            #If you were mentioned add this reaction
            await message.add_reaction('')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

The Member ID is a normal number so its just an int.
and message.mentions gives you a list with members, who were mentioned.
We have to check for all members in the list if their Member.ID is equal to yours.

Have a nice day

Comment: No problem. Im glad if it helped you. I would recommend you to look into the documentation of discord.py. Everytime when I am stuck I look into it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yeah, I already based almost half of my bot with it, but I had a problem because I clearly have a lack of knowledge in python... Thanks a lot ! :)